# sqlite does not returned data according to the insertion

Tags: android

// Getting All Data

```
 public List<SQLiteData> getAllData() {
        List<SQLiteData> dataList = new ArrayList<SQLiteData>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + MENU_TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                SQLiteData data = new SQLiteData();
                data.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                data.setMenuName(cursor.getString(1));
                data.setMenuImage(cursor.getString(2));
                dataList.add(data);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            db.close();
        }
        return dataList;
    }
```

i have used this to get the data from sqlite. But it does not return the data in normal order. I maen while inserting the data the data order is

```
D/Insert All Data: tikc
11-09 13:31:30.994 9877-9877/com.ingrils.organisatiom.activity.resturant D/Insert All Data: Pastries3
11-09 13:31:31.004 9877-9877/com.ingrils.organisatiom.activity.resturant D/Insert All Data: Main Course
11-09 13:31:31.004 9877-9877/com.ingrils.organisatiom.activity.resturant D/Insert All Data: Coffee
```

but while selecting it is returning

```
D/Get All Data: Pastries3
11-09 13:31:31.014 9877-9877/com.ingrils.organisatiom.activity.resturant D/Get All Data: Main Course
11-09 13:31:31.014 9877-9877/com.ingrils.organisatiom.activity.resturant D/Get All Data: Coffee
11-09 13:31:31.014 9877-9877/com.ingrils.organisatiom.activity.resturant D/Get All Data: tikc
```

why i am not getting the data according to the insertion data

Comment: SQLite never promised to keep your stuff in a certain order internally :) but when retrieving data you can always write "ORDER BY..." in your SELECT statement

Comment: To be exact, no RDBMS grants the data to be returned sorted.

Answer (score 1):

you must use `ORDER BY  columnname` keyword to order your data

Comment: I think to get the normal data according to the insertion why should i use order by

Comment: because data is not listed in database as you inserted. and database has it's own priority for storing data.

Comment: @Gokarnapantha You don't want to understand: no RDBMS grants the data to be returned sorted. ORDER BY is the only way to sort your data. (sorry, before I mistakenly addressed this comment to @karimkhan)